# MUI Calendar - separate Year and Month dropdowns

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to customize MUI calendar to have separate drop-downs (the one of the picture below has a dropdown with a value "September 2023", I need a separate dropdown for "September" and for "2023".

Ideally I would like the drop-down to call a custom form, but I did not find an easy way to customize it, besides completely rewriting the control.

[image]